# NSPredicate: Unable to parse the format string for relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, entity-relationship, one-to-one

I have two entity named "`CIUser`" and "`CICast`". "`CIUser`" entity has an one-to-one relationship with "`CICast`" named "`cast`".

```
CIUser : 
    -> userId(Int)
    -> isLive(bool)
    -> name(String)

CICast:
    -> castId(Int)
    -> lastUpdate(Date)
```

Now my requirement is to fetch all the users who are currently live and there lastUpdate is less than a calculated date. So I had prepared my fetch request like

```
let time = //an calculated NSDate object

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CIUser")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isLive == %@ AND cast.lastUpdate <= %@", NSNumber(bool: true), time)
```

But it crash the application throwing `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "isLive == %@ AND cast.lastUpdate <= %@"'`

Can anyone help me where I am doing wrong, or what approach should I take. Suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that "CAST" is a *reserved word* in the predicate format
syntax, and the reserved words are case-insensitive. So this conflicts
with your  relationship named "cast".

As a workaround, use the `%K` key path substitution:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isLive == %@ AND %K <= %@",
                            NSNumber(bool: true), "cast.lastUpdate", time)
```

or rename the relationship. You may want to use the `%K` expansion
generally to avoid such problems:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@ AND %K <= %@",
                           "isLive", NSNumber(bool: true),
                           "cast.lastUpdate", time)
```

For more information, see [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)
in the "Predicate Programming Guide".